# Looking for Spring Cloud ECS Connector Documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-connectors

I'm trying to set up connection to a file storage bucket with Spring Cloud ECS Connector

```
import com.emc.ecs.connector.spring.S3Connector;

public S3Connector s3() {
        S3Connector result = this.connectionFactory().service(S3Connector.class);
        this.connectionFactory().
        return result;
    }
```

However, I'm new to s3 bucket and don't know how to use its constructor and the parameters it takes. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.emc.ecs/spring-cloud-ecs-connector/1.0.0

Does anyone know any documentation for Spring Cloud ECS Connector and S3Connector that describe its methods, constructor and how to setting bucket information(secret key, access key, endpoint, bucket name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the project page: https://github.com/spiegela/spring-cloud-ecs-connector

[S3Connector source with javadoc](https://github.com/spiegela/spring-cloud-ecs-connector/blob/1caee1ac74bd2d0b59d9d46db3ca848e33364e2f/src/main/java/com/emc/ecs/connector/spring/S3Connector.java)

Also, there's a `S3ServiceConnectorCreator`. Example usage from https://github.com/spiegela/spring-cloud-ecs-connector/blob/master/src/test/java/com/emc/ecs/connector/spring/S3ServiceConnectorCreatorTest.java :

```
private S3ServiceConnectorCreator s3ServiceConnectorCreator = new S3ServiceConnectorCreator();
...
String myBucket = "myBucket";
String endpoint = "http://10.20.40.3:9020";
S3ServiceInfo serviceInfo = new S3ServiceInfo("s3-1", "myPublicKey", "mySecretKey", endpoint, myBucket);
S3Connector connector = s3ServiceConnectorCreator.create(serviceInfo, null);
```

Comment: Appreciate! By the way, for the serviceInfo() constructor, the first parameter is String id. Is the id same as "Owners" of the bucket? I cannot see any variable named "ID" on s3 browser.

Comment: The [javadoc](https://github.com/spiegela/spring-cloud-ecs-connector/blob/1caee1ac74bd2d0b59d9d46db3ca848e33364e2f/src/main/java/com/emc/ecs/connector/S3ServiceInfo.java#L20) says it's "the service ID of the provisioned service". Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Dell ECS to give you more specifics.